# Closing the View sets properties of the ViewModel to null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I use a `DataGrid` to display a list of **Animals** in my WPF application:

[image]

The value for `ComboBox` "Bucht" is loaded from another collection **Pens** in my ViewModel using the following XAML, which works fine:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Animals, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="EPC" Binding="{Binding Epc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Visual ID" Binding="{Binding VisualId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Geschlecht" Binding="{Binding Gender, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bucht">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Pens, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:AdministrationView}}}" 
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Pen, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding Pen.PenId}" 
                              SelectedValuePath="PenId">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:AdministrationView}}}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

**Now the problem**: If the View is closed, e.g. by clicking on another View, some of the properties of my ViewModel are set to null. If I reopen the View the Pens are set to null which looks like that:

[image]

The debugger confirms it:

[image]

I think this is related to the question [WPF View sets ViewModel properties to null on closing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1002098/220636). But I can't use the workaround provided in those answers (i.e. setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` in my `ComboBox`) because I save the entity directly after edit, so LostFocus update is to late.

**Is there any clean way to avoid that behaviour?**

---

Comment: Can you post the code for the Pens property in the ViewModel?

Comment: And the Pen property

Comment: Its not creating a new instance of the ViewModel class every time you load the view is it?

Comment: @GlenThomas No the ViewModel is created once at application startup

Comment: Is the ViewModel being create in your View constructor?

public View()
{
    DataContext = new VIewModel();
}

Comment: Ok. I would put a breakpoint on the set of the Pen property and when it gets set to null, see where the stack trace leads to.

Comment: All ViewModels are created in a MainViewModel and glued to their corresponding View using a DataTemplate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84558/discussion-between-glen-thomas-and-nabulke).

Comment: What is AdministrationView? is it outside the view being replaced?

Comment: @Liero AdministrationView is the View that is closed. The DataGrid above is part of this View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the ItemsSource binding. When you navigate to other view, the ItemsSource binding returns null, items from combobox are removed, SelectedItem is set to null and SelectedItem.Binding updates updates Pen property.

You can try one of following:

1. Try to use **OneTime binding** in the **ItemsSource** property, so it is not cleared.
2. ViewModel's responsibility is to allow view to bind easily. Add **Pens property next to Pen** property. Never mind that it will be the same foreach animal. It will be just reference to the same collection, so no performance or consistency problems.

One more comment. Remove the `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue` Binding. First of all, they conflicts with SelectedItem, second, you used them incorrectly - SelectedValuePath="PenId" would make sense, if you had PenId property instead of Pen property.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the `SelectedItem` binding to `Default`

Comment: If I change the UpdateSourceTrigger to Default, the changes in the combobox selection are not propagated to the ViewModel. So my SaveCommand is called (by the EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged") but in the ViewModel I don't see the new values.
So it does change the behaviour, but not in the desired way.

Comment: This is strange as I never set the UpdateSourceTrigger on the SelectedItem binding of a ComboBox and it always works for me. Maybe because it is in the DataGrid it works differently.

Comment: I think the problem is that the DataGrid cell is in an edit mode and needs to commit changes. Trying to figure out how to do this...

Comment: Hi Glen. I think the problem starts with the View object being discarded. Somehow the View then sets some values to null (i.e. the combobox SelectedItem), which also sets those values in my ViewModel to null (by databinding).

Comment: That is the problem with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. I don't think that is the right way to go. I'm looking at making a custom DataGridColumn that will commit changes to the cell when the ComboBox selection changes

Answer (score -1):

change the itemssource binding and try once. I mean instead of binding from Relative source datacontext, try to bind from viewModel and check once.

Comment: Currently you are binding  from relative source for combobox itemssource   , if possible try to binding directly (with out relate source ) and check once. I also faced this kind of behaiour for combobox if i am binding with releative source.