# How to avoid the View being disposed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using a `ContentControl` im my WPF application to show different *Views* to the user.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>
```

By pushing a button the user can switch the value of `CurrentPageViewModel` to another *ViewModel* object and, with the help of a `DataTemplate`, switch to another *View*.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:AdministrationViewModel}">
    <view:AdministrationView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HealthViewModel}">
    <view:HealthView />
</DataTemplate>
```

So far so good.

---

My **problem** starts whenever the *View* is switched. Then the old *View* is discarded and the Framework deletes/disposes the *View* object.

Grid sort settings are therefore lost and what's even worse, some of the *Views* values are set to null. The null values are propagated to my *ViewModel* by Databinding, which totaly messes up my *ViewModel* data!

**How can I prevent the View object to be deleted/discarded?**

Comment: Should not happens. Views are meant to be disposed in MVVM. So you have to look closer why you get `null` values instead of preventing view from being disposed.

Comment: @Sinatr : I asked that in my related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31698289/220636). Unfortunately I didn't get real answers or explanations.

Comment: The problem might be very specific. It could be some control / behavior / event problem (e.g. it doesn't work correctly with bindings). In the setter of property what become `null` do a check for `null` and set breakpoint inside to see stack calls (who does that and why). It should be possible to solve issue without letting view to live forever, e.g. informing ViewModel about view being changed in advance and disable setters logic. I am using data templates myself with many views without any issue. ViewModel data is kept between view changed. I am not using `DataGrid` or `Interaction` (blend).

Comment: What exactly happens when view is switched? Can you show related ViewModel code (talking about `CurrentPageViewModel` property).

Comment: @Sinatr I did set a breakpoint as suggested, but the stack trace shows only one entry: "External Code".

Comment: @Sinatr I added an example solution in the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31698289/220636). I tried to strip the example down to the important parts...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest but very powerfull solution to control your views' life is using converter instead of datatemplates:

```
<ContentControl  Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel, Converter={StaticResource ViewModelToViewConverter}"/>
```

```
public class ViewModelToViewConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

       //use naming convention or custom settings here to get view type
        var viewModelType = value.GetType();
        var viewType = ... 

        var view = (FrameworkElement) YourIocContainer.Resolve(viewType);
        view.DataContext = value;
        return view;
    }
    ...
 }
```

You need to setup your IoC so for particular view's it will return singleton instance. IoC also allows you dependency injecion into your views. Instead of IoC you may use your own factory pattern implementation.

However, ViewModel properties should not be messed, when view is disconnected from visual three. There's probably another issue in bindings and you should open new question for this

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks good. I already opened another question concerning the base issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31698289/220636).