# Navigation with Frame and Combobox MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to get my head around MVVM, i'm currently stuck on how to handle navigation.

Currently I have a page and within that page is a frame, that frame is responsible for framing in various other pages. Navigation was previously handled with a drop down box and on selection changed it would navigate that way.

I'm not sure how I could do this without touching the frame from the model view which would end up breaking mvvm.

In the end what I am trying to accomplish is, clicking on the combobox, selecting an item and then having then frame below navigate to the correct view.

I'm not using Prism or any other framework with MVVM, just trying to do it all manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ComboBox` would display an `ObservableCollection` of frame items exposed by your main viewmodel, and the viewmodel will have another property for the selected item.

Your main viewmodel and the frame item viewmodels all inherit from a `ViewModelBase` class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and maybe some other stuff.

So, C#:

```
public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> FrameItems { get; protected set; }

private ViewModelBase _selectedFrameItem;
public ViewModelBase SelectedFrameItem {
    get { return _selectedFrameItem; }
    set {
        value = _selectedFrameItem;
        //  Defined in ViewModelBase
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Your main viewmodel will populate `FrameItems` in its constructor:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    FrameItems = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelbase> {
        new IceCreamMenu(),
        new SmurfOptions(),
        new MagicSparklePonyFourierTransformConfiguration()
    };
}
```

Every frame item is a subclass of `ViewModelBase`. It exposes properties with notifications, including `ObservableCollections` of any set of child things it may have. And we'll display it by writing a datatemplate for it in just a bit.

Let's assume that you've given your `ViewModelBase` class a `String Title { get; set; }` property. Or maybe you'll want to write a subclass of `ViewModelBase` that introduces `Title`; your call. For now let's put it in `ViewModelBase` for simplicity.

XAML -- this leaves out all the layout, but you don't need that here.

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding FrameItems}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFrameItem}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Title"
    />

<Frame Content={Binding SelectedFrameItem}" />
```

OK, but how on earth does it know what to do with `SelectedFrameItem`?!

Easy! Write a resource dictionary called, say, `ViewModelDataTemplates.xaml`, and merge it into `App.xaml` so its contents are "visible" in any XAML in your application.

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Source is a relative path from project root directory -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewModelDataTemplates.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

...plus whatever theme stuff or whatever.

In `ViewModelDataTemplates.xaml`, define data templates for your frame item classes.

Say you've got an `IceCreamMenu` viewmodel, with a collection of `Flavors`

```
public ObservableCollection<IceCreamFlavor> Flavors { get; protected set; }
```

...and a `SelectedFlavor`. You'd define the namespace `vm` appropriately with an `xmlns:vm` attribute on the resource dictionary.

ViewModelDataTemplates.xaml

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:IceCreamMenu}">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Flavors}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFlavor}"
            />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:IceCreamFlavor}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border 
            Height="20" 
            Width="20" 
            Margin="4" 
            Background={Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" 
            />
        <Label Content="Name" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

If you've got existing `UserControls` that you want to use via datatemplates, that's easy: Say you've got a `NotesTabView` `UserControl` that's a view for your `NotesTabViewModel`, you could define a DataTemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NotesTabViewModel}">
    <vw:NotesTabView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: So when I do this, I select an item from the combo box, it changes the content of the frame to just the name of the view model it instantiates, as if it just does a .tostring() method on it.

The whole DataTemplate defines how it shows the data correct?

Well the thing if I have a separate view for each page already created, so it just needs to move to the correct view

Comment: Sounds like it's not finding the datatemplate for the viewmodel type you put in the frame. Are you merging your datatemplates.xaml in App.xaml?

Comment: @Tbooty Added App.xaml to my answer

Comment: So it is finding the Data template, so that would mean for each page, i'd have to make out the data template? As each page will have different contents

Comment: @Tbooty If by "page" you mean the different classes that will be displayed in the frame, yes. Each one gets its own DataTemplate. If two of them could share the same data template, you can do that too (I'll add that to my answer).

Comment: I'll add a bit of back story. So this was an app built out in WPF that I am "attempting" to convert to MVVM. The app itself is quite large so I am converting one tool. The way it's handled right now is the folder has a main class that displays the combo box and it has a frame, when a user selects something from the combobox it will browse to the WPF page. So the UI for each page is already made, would I be better off just making each of those a template from the xaml code and work that way?

Comment: If they're UserControls or something, that's easy. Adding to answer.

Comment: @Tbooty Added to end of answer. We've got a million of those in our line-of-business application.

Comment: one last question, when I put the usercontent inside the data template, it displays the entire data templaye instead of just the name, the navigation works and all but the combobox should be displaying the name of the user content control, not actually rendering the entire content control. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tbooty did you give the combo box DisplayMemberPath?

Comment: Ahh that is what I was missing,

Answer (score 0):

@EdPlunkett: As an alternative to DataTemplate for each view, you can bind your frame to selected page viewmodel using ViewModelToViewConverter like I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31721236/475727

Implicit DataTemplates and DataTemplateSelectors are unique to WPF and XAML, so people think it's recommended solution, but I think it's not suitable for navigation. It feels hackish and it smells with violation of DRY principle.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. Of course, that does imply having some kind of IoC setup.

Comment: But yes, if implicit templates only work on WPF, they're not much of a solution elsewhere!